# Blender colors don't match with the system ones

Tags: color, color-management

Colors on blender are not the same as they are in photo viewer (how they should be)
[image: blender "adaptation" on the left, right colors on the right]

[image]

Comment: You probably need to mess with [these settings](https://imgur.com/a/DPWp472). Try changing the *Look* and *View Transform* settings.

Comment: @Jakemoyo indeed I did (thought that it would help), but it seems not to be a fix in this situation